# Remove variable after chunk is executed

Tags: r, r-markdown, local-variables, chunks

In Rmarkdown, when I execute some code, all variables I created end up in the common namespace of the whole notebook where other chunks can access them. However I often make temporary variables that don't really need to persist after the chunk is over. They clutter up my variable list, my autocomplete dropdown, and generally cause confusion and subtle bugs (eg. if I forget to initialize a variable that was used by a previous chunk).

For example:

````
Calculate the area of a circle:
```{r}
r = 1.23

pi = 3.14  
temp = 1.23^2

area = pi * temp
```
````

If I only want `r` and `area` to persist after running this, how can I "mark" `pi` and `temp` to be cleared after the chunk is done?

Comment: You can explicitly remove them with `rm`. But if this is a common problem for you, I would advise picking better variable names. In the case of your example, maybe you would call `temp` r_sq` instead - a meaningful name. This is generally a good practice for programming.

Comment: @Gregor Picking better variable names is of course always good practice, but please bear in mind that the example is necessarily contrived as I'm not very imaginative. I hope you'll take my word that there exist legitimate cases of this issue where the variable names are as good as they're gonna get, and still there is a problem.

Comment: Then use `rm`! I addressed that too! `rm(pi, temp)` at the end of your chunk. Or, in a separate, `echo = FALSE`, chunk immediately following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note pi is a built-in constant in R, you do not need to declare your own approximation.

A good solution is to wrap the content of each chunk in a function. In this case, your chunk would look like this:

```
r <- 1.23
circle_area <- function(x) {
pi*(r^2)
}
area <- circle_area()
```

If having the function `circle_area` persist is also a problem, the advice to use `rm()` is correct. In that case, I'd say if your chunks are sufficiently complex it means you only have to worry about removing one name per chunk.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Btw, I know pi is a constant already, it's meant as an example.

Comment: Fair enough, you just never know!